Can't add new command when connection is in closed state with NestJS TypeORM
I am facing an issue with the MySQL database in AWS RDS, connecting using the AWS IAM token. I have summarized the issue here - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/11111#issue-2613088839, if anyone has any ideas, do let me know.
